# How to get the posted file name after successfull upload in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net mvc web api. I am trying to upload a image through a post request like,

```
<form action="/api/mypictures/12" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="somefile">File</label>
        <input name="somefile" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

i havebeen followed the following procedure,

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage AddImage(HttpRequestMessage request, int id)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
                {
                    return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, new HttpError() { { "status", "failed" }, { "message", "Invalid file format" } });
                }
                else
                {
                    string PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
                    var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);
                    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(
                        t =>
                        {
                            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                        }
                    );
                    Photo photo = new Photo();
                    photo.Id = id;
                    **photo.Image = "Image that uploaded recently";**
                    photo.IsUserAllowed = true;
                    if (barrepository.AddImage(photo) == 1)
                    {
                        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new HttpError() { { "status", "success" }, { "message", "file uploaded successfully" } });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new HttpError() { { "status", "success" }, { "message", "unable to store the image into database" } });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new HttpError() { { "status", "failed" }, { "message", ex.Message } });
            }
        }
```

and my CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider class is like,

```
public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
    {
        public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path)
            : base(path)
        { }

        public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            var name = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName) ? DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")+"_"+headers.ContentDisposition.FileName : "NoName";
            return name.Replace("\"", string.Empty); 
        }
    }
```

and the above procedure saves the file into mentioned folder nicely. but i need to store that uploaded file name into my database table after successfull image upload. how could i get the posted file's file name after successfull upload. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file name like below:

```
var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);


            CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider resultProvider = t.Result;
            string fileName = t.FileData.First().LocalFileName;
                    }
                );
```